# Firebase cloud messaging service not running on Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on a chat app for which i am using Firebase cloud messaging.
Everything works fine till android nougat , But as i have explored Android Oreo doesn't support background services . That's why my firebase push notification service is not running when app is stopped .

```
onMessageReceived() is not called in background
```

Please help me with this how can i receive message even when my app is closed on Oreo.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you building with?  Should be [10.2.1 or later](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android): _The Firebase Android SDK (v10.2.1) includes updates to provide compatibility with Android O_

Comment: @BobSnyder i am using 11.8.0

Comment: Are your sending a notification or data message?  If data message, it must be sent with high priority to wake a sleeping device.

Comment: @BobSnyder yes i am doing the same i.e. data message with high priority

Comment: Don't know what else to suggest.  I just tested using an API 26 emulator and worked.

Comment: Ensure the device or emulator you are testing on has a version of Google Play services installed that is compatible with SDK 11.8.0.  Should be 11.9.X.   Look in the logcat at the time the app initializes for this warning: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`

Comment: If there is a crash, always show the full stack trace.  If you have code that's not working the way you expect, also show that and explain what's happening.

Comment: Hi nishant. With your current post, it is probable that it would be closed, since it doesn't contain any details such as your current code in question. With that said, have you properly implemented [Notification Channels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)?